# Quality of my computer Specs for mining

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, hardware

I am just wondering on how good my computer could be and if there are any steps i have failed to take to make sure it is running/mining at its fullest potential. Also any tips on hardware upgrades for better performance would be greatly appreciated as well.

My hardware includes:

EVGA 500W 80+ Bronze certified ATX Power Supply

Kingston HyperX Fury Black 8GB (2 x 4GB) DDR4-2133 Memory

Sandisk SSD PLUS 240GB 2.5" Solid Slate Drive

MSI GAMING Radeon RX 480 GDDR5 4GB CrossFire VR Ready FinFET DirectX 12 Graphics Card (RX 480 ARMOR 4G OC)

Intel Boxed Core I5-6600 FC-LGA14C 3.30 Ghz 6 M Processor Cache 4 LGA 1151 BX80662I56600

also is there anything software wise i can do to make my gpu run at max potential.

Thanks for he help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your computer looks fine for mining.  There are plenty of profitability calculators out there to estimate your earnings based on your hashrate.

The only thing you could do to significantly increase your mining power is to get another GPU.

CPU mining isn't' efficient for Ethereum, but something like Zcash could net you some extra profitability.

Comment: yeah i am only going on my gpu, however i have seen such things as this and am unsure what they do or how they affect the graphics card, http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/ if you could explain in laymans terms lol

Comment: That is an SDK, something for developers.  You wouldn't use that unless you were doing something like editing the mining software I believe.

Comment: interesting, so this is not necessary to "unlock" my cards potential or anything like that.

Comment: Correct. You could try overclocking your card with a GPU utility such as MSI Afterburner.  Overclocking the memory could give you a performance boost.